# Regex: Contador de cuantas veces se encontró un carácter especifico

Tags: javascript, regex

**¿Hay una forma en Regex de hacer un contador de cuantas veces se encontró un carácter especifico para luego poder usarlo en el futuro?** Quiero saber cuantos "(" se abren para luego cuando se cierren esos ")" capturar lo que sigue después. Algo parecido a tener un grupo previo con \N o \k.

```
2xx+x**35.9*8CA(x+(y+jj3(y3+x**3)))
```

Tendría que cortar 2xx y lo que resta en otro indice. Usando `str.match`.

Comment: ¿Podría explicar mejor esto de "Tendría que cortar 2xx y lo que resta en otro indice"?

Comment: "Tendría que cortar 2xx y lo que resta en otro indice". Yo quiero dividir cualquier expresión en términos (+ o -) usando str.match.

Comment: Si lo he entenido, quieres se parar por los `+` , pero sin "romper" paréntesis? Otra pregunta: siempre se encuentran signos `+`? O también podría haber signos `-`? Cuales son todas las operaciones permitidas?